# How nginx works when server in upstream is die

Tags: nginx

Helli! I have problem with **nginx on my work** . Nginx send requests, when server in upstream is die

```
upstream test {
    server server1:90;
    server server2:90;
}


 location / {
    proxy_pass http://test;
}
```

That is, when server2 stops responding, requests to it continue to be proxied anyway

**However:**
I decided to deploy Nginx on a local machine, with the same upstream and location settings

```
upstream test {
    server server1:90;
    server server2:90;
}


 location / {
    proxy_pass http://test;
}
```

Only in this case Nginx stops sending requests to the non-working server.
That is, when server2 stops responding, requests are proxied only to server1, but there are records in the logs about the unavailability of server2

The difference is that nginx 1.21 is on the workstation (here I get 502), and on the local 1.18 (everything works correctly here)

What could be the problem on the working load balancer? I suspect that there is a passive healtcheck setting in the configuration files, which decides whether to send a request to an idle server or not

I tried to search for a passive healthcheck configuration, but I didn't find an answer